# Stellaris lm3s8962 GPIO input failing

Tags: ssi, gpio

I am using bit banging to control the pins on the SSI for switchable microwire/spi. I can send the data to an eeprom (control+address) with chip select configured correctly but get no output. The configuration code is:

```
    // SSI SPI initialization

    ulClkGPIO = GPIO_PORTA_BASE + (GPIO_PIN_2 << 2);
    ulFssGPIO = GPIO_PORTA_BASE + (GPIO_PIN_7 << 2);
    ulRxGPIO = GPIO_PORTA_BASE + (GPIO_PIN_4 << 2);
    ulTxGPIO = GPIO_PORTA_BASE + (GPIO_PIN_5 << 2);

    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(ulFssGPIO & 0xfffff000,
                                  (ulFssGPIO & 0x00000fff) >> 2);

    //
    // Set the Fss pin high.
    //
    HWREG(ulFssGPIO) = 255;

    //
    // Configure the Clk pin.
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(ulClkGPIO & 0xfffff000,
                              (ulClkGPIO & 0x00000fff) >> 2);

    //
    // Set the Clk pin low
    //
    HWREG(ulClkGPIO) = 0;

    //
    // Configure the Tx pin and set it high.
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(ulTxGPIO & 0xfffff000,
                              (ulTxGPIO & 0x00000fff) >> 2);
    HWREG(ulTxGPIO) = 255;

    //
    // Configure the Rx pin.
    //
    MAP_GPIODirModeSet(ulRxGPIO & 0xfffff000,
                       (ulRxGPIO & 0x00000fff) >> 2, GPIO_DIR_MODE_IN);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(ulRxGPIO & 0xfffff000,
                         (ulRxGPIO & 0x00000fff) >> 2,
                         GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPD);
//    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(ulRxGPIO & 0xfffff000,
//                             (ulRxGPIO & 0x00000fff) >> 2);
```

For I2C I use the hardware peripheral and all is working fine. The bit banging for byte write and byte read on spi is below.

```
void sendSPIByte(unsigned char data)
{
    unsigned char count;
    for(count = 0; count < 8; count++) {
        HWREG(ulTxGPIO) = (data & 0x80) ? 255 : 0;
        data <<= 1;
        SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay
        HWREG(ulClkGPIO) = 255;
        SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay
        HWREG(ulClkGPIO) = 0;
        SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay
    }
}

unsigned char getSPIByte(void) {
    unsigned char count;
    unsigned char data;
    data = 0;
    for(count = 0; count < 8; count++) {
        data <<= 1;
        data |= (HWREG(ulRxGPIO) ? 1 : 0);
        HWREG(ulClkGPIO) = 255;
        SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay
        HWREG(ulClkGPIO) = 0;
        SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay
    }
    return data;
}

void
SPIRead(unsigned long ulOffset, unsigned char ulCount)
{
    //
    // Assert the SSI chip select.
    //
    HWREG(ulFssGPIO) = 0;
    SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay

    unsigned char controlByte;
    controlByte = ((ulOffset & 0x1) << 3) | SPI_READ;
    ulDataTx[0] = controlByte;
    sendSPIByte(ulDataTx[0]);
    ulDataTx[0] = ulOffset & 0xff;
    sendSPIByte(ulDataTx[0]);
    SysCtlDelay((SysCtlClockGet() / 10000)); // 10 khz delay
    unsigned char dataRx[1];
    unsigned int count;
    for(count = 0; count < ulCount; count++) {
        dataRx[0] = getSPIByte();
        ulDataRx[count] = dataRx[0];
    }
    //
    // Deassert the SSI chip select.
    //
    HWREG(ulFssGPIO) = 255;

    UARTSend(ulDataRx, ulCount);
}
```

This is my first use of stellaris. I have investigated weak pull down for the input and other possible configuration issues to no avail. I have other custom hardware using the same bit banging technique which works 100%. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

UPDATE: I have tested the input pin by feeding a signal in and the input is working. However I receive only 0xff when trying to read the eeprom. I have captured the outputs to the chip, data out, clk and cs, and these appear to be fine. Why would the output not respond?? This is driving me crazy. Can anyone help??

LATEST: Feeding MOSI straight back into MISO results in mainly 0xff with occasional low bits in the received data. This is when sending out all 0x00. This indicates some sort of input failure.

This question can be thought of as self answered although may be useful for others. The loopback failed because of a bad connection. DOH! Once I had established that the loopback worked I then began to wonder if it was voltage related. The eeprom under test may not operate at the 3v level supplied by the Stellaris. I still have to confirm this but does show to check the obvious first before plowing into code. In which case a 3 to 5 volt level shifter should sort the problem.